# 301 Redirect URLs with special characters to homepage htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, lamp

I have about 90 URLs that look like this....

```
www.domain.com/index.php?page=about-us
www.domain.com/index.php?page=Testimonials
www.domain.com/index.php?page=contact-us-2
www.domain.com/index.php?mact=News,cntnt01,detail,0&cntnt01articleid=184&cntnt01origid=68&cntnt01returnid=68
```

etc. etc.

I need to do a wildcard 301 redirect on any URL that contains /index.php? to the homepage. How do I go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as **your very first rule** in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php[?/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:page|mact)= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=301]
```

`?` after `/` in target URI is for stripping off any query string that exists after `index.php?`

Comment: It hasn't worked no but I don't think it is because of your code. For some reason my site looks to be stripping out index.php before the URLs even load. It's a wordpress site. So the url becomes www.domain.com/?page=contact-us-2. 

If i remove '+index\.php' will that work?

Thanks

Comment: like so...

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php[?/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: How do I edit the above .htaccess to 301 redirect URLs to home page if the URLs contain "?page=" and "?mact=" for example --
'www.domain.com?page=page-a' and ''www.domain.com?mact=page-a' etc. etc.

Comment: I have added a new rule for that in my answer. But in future please don't post new requirements via comments section. Prefer to post a new question for new problems.

Comment: thanks :) sorry it seemed a waste of time creating a new question when all the info was here but i will do it next time :) . One little issue we have with the updated code is when we access plugin pages in wp-admin e.g.  "/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wp-seo-schema" we are redirected to the home page. How can we exclude wp-admin pages from redirecting to home page with this rewrite rule?

Comment: See that's the reason this practice of adding new requirement via comments is not a good practice. Now you have further changes into new requirement.

Comment: You may try last rule as `RewriteRule !^wp-admin/ /? [L,R=301,NC]`